# Excel VBA that loops through the folder and move data to the next column

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro that loops through all of the files in a folder *m* then opens it and looks for the words starting with *"Page"* in *K* column and then shifts it to the next column. The code I am using is

```
Public Sub Loop_through_folder_page_no()
'DECLARE AND SET VARIABLES
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim Filename As String
Dim Path As String
Path = "C:\xlsFolder\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")

'--------------------------------------------
'OPEN EXCEL FILES
 Do While Len(Filename) > 0  'IF NEXT FILE EXISTS THEN
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)
'
Dim K As Range
Dim r As Range
Set K = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("K:K"))

  For Each r In K   'ERRORS HERE WITH Runtime error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error
    If Left(r.Text, 4) = "Page" Then
        r.Copy r.Offset(0, 1)
        r.Clear
    End If
  Next r

ActiveWorkbook.Save


wbk.Close True
Filename = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

This code is giving an error.  I cannot figure it out what's wrong with it.

Comment: **On which line does the error occur ??**

Comment: Also, what error does it give?

Comment: Also insure *Public Sub Loop_through_folder_page_no()* is all on one line.

Comment: It is giving Runtime error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: please specify on which line it gives the error. (press "debug" when you receive the error message and let us no which line is highlighted)

Comment: it is giving error on the line starting with "For Each r In K"

Comment: r is a range, you tell VBA to iterate through all ranges of the range "K", try to be a bit more specific: `for each r in k.cells`

Comment: I changed it, and now it is giving Error " Method 'Intersect' of Object '_Global' failed"

Comment: try `activesheet.range("K:K")` instead of just range. Do you have only one sheet in your files / are you sure the desired sheet is selected? Please check again whether intersection of used range and column K is really exist.

Comment: @MátéJuhász, you should move your comment to an answer. mb1987, you need to use the at symbol to 'ping' someone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try activesheet.range("K:K") instead of just range. Do you have only one sheet in your files / are you sure the desired sheet is selected? Please check again whether intersection of used range and column K is really exist.